# How to create a folder shortcut on desktop in ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS? Gives error after creation

Tags: bash, directory, shortcuts

How to create a folder shortcut on ubuntu?
I used [this method](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1235661/how-to-create-desktop-shortcuts-for-folders-in-ubuntu-20-04) to create the shortcut as well as used `ln -s /media/alcatraz/New Volume2/Codes ~/Desktop/`.

If I use the first method, link is created successfully but after restart an error pops up saying "Broken link, Can not open this File because it is a Broken Symlink" and if I use the second method it shows this error instantly when double clicking the folder shortcut. Please note that my source folder is on another partition.

Comment: For us to fully understand your issue, you should provide details of what OS/release you're using, plus the actual command you use.  If using a *live* system or certain types of mounts, the problem you experience can be expected, on other systems what you want would be expected, but you've not provided specific details as to your OS/release, nor the directories involved or types of mounts (file-system etc details)

Comment: @guiverc Thank you so much for responding. I have updated the details you requested. I am using ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. Also for the first method I am opening desktop using files as well as the parent directory of folder I wanted to share and then I am pressing alt and shift and dragging from source to destination in files.

Comment: Is the volume you want always connected?  as `/media/` is usually used for *ad-hoc* type of connections though can be used for *always* connected to.  Did you add the connection so it's mounted automatically? (eg. I tend to add my mounts via *file-system table* (ie. `/etc/fstab`) meaning they'll be connected automatically (or not depending on options I control; ie. auto/noauto), though there are other ways of auto-mounting as well, but you've not specified if this was done & what method, or you've left it for the user on the GUI to mount it; meaning symlink will be broken till mounted by user)

Comment: Ubuntu is on the same ssd, just partitions are different. Rest I didn't perform any mounting changes. I am very new to linux and am not familiar with mounting operations being handled automatically or manually. I just drag and drop as shared on that link or try to create a symlink as mentioned on the code.